# Uppercase limits

Tags: math-mode, macros

Sorry if this is a too-simple question, but anyway.

Is there a simple way of writing in LaTeX projective and inductive limits that begin with uppercase (`Lim`)?

This is what we usually have
https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2010/10/02/direct-and-inverse-limit-in-latex/.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator\Lim{Lim}` ?

Comment: Thanks but see the example linked. Proj and Ind limits have an arrow below. I need the same but beginning with uppercase.

Comment: You only asked about the case, the arrows are same as normal `\Lim_{\rightarrow}` (or `\leftarrow`) or  `\Lim\limits_{\rightarrow}` if you want to force that position even in inline math.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can patch `\varinjlim` and `\varprojlim` to use “Lim” instead of “lim” and to this end it's sufficient to patch the internal macro `\varlim@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\varlim@}{lim}{Lim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim \quad \varprojlim
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also take the opportunity to make the arrows a bit smaller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\varlim@}{lim}{Lim}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varinjlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjlim \quad \varprojlim
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the old commands, you can patch copies thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\varLim@\varlim@
\NewCommandCopy\varinjLim\varinjlim
\NewCommandCopy\varprojLim\varprojlim
\xpatchcmd{\varinjLim}{\varlim@}{\varLim@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojLim}{\varlim@}{\varLim@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varLim@}{lim}{Lim}{}{}
% smaller arrows
\xpatchcmd{\varinjlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varinjLim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojlim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\varprojLim}{\textstyle}{\scriptstyle}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\varinjLim \quad \varprojLim
\quad
\varinjlim \quad \varprojlim
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way from moving from this limit to the former in the document? "Something Lim but after lim".

Comment: @hansficter Yes, it's possible. See edit.

Comment: Many thanks!! For some reason "\NewCommandCopy" appears as undefined. I have used "\let" instead, and works smoothly.

Comment: @hansficter Better update your TeX distribution…